# Approximating a simple sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, logarithms, approximation

Can somone help me find an assymptotic formula for n, for fixed x , for this sum , perhaps an inequality would be even better, or some bound on the error.
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\log(kx)}$$

I need somthing better then the integral from 1 to n of ln(kx) with respect to k.
Its also okay if you use special functions, like the logarithmic integral.

Comment: In what limit do you want an approximation?  $x \to \infty$ for fixed $n$?  $n \to \infty$ for fixed $x$?

Comment: n->infinity, for fixed x, that is an asymptotic formula in terms of n and x

Comment: @boby Why can't you use one account to post your questions? I have already told this to you at-least twice (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233268/simplifying-very-large-euler-product#comment517819_233268) and (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229399/proving-a-simple-inequality#comment510818_229399)

Comment: Use the Euler-Maclaurin series as suggested below. The expression doesn't in and of itself have a closed form that simplifies to elementary functions, nor have I found any special function that neatly fits your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

The Euler-Maclaurin series for $\sum_k 1/\log(kx)$ starts
$$ F(k) = \frac{\text{Li}(kx)}{x} -  \frac{1}{2 \ln(kx)} - \frac{1}{12 \ln(kx)^2 k} 
+ \frac{3 + 3 \ln(kx) + \ln(kx)^2}{360 \ln(kx)^4 k^3} + \ldots
$$

That is, we should have
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\log(kx)} \approx F(n+1) + C$$
where $C$ is a constant.